# Is it possible to share FB session between an ios application and a WebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, facebook-comments, facebook-ios-sdk

In my ios application, I integrated FBSDK for "post to wall" and "Connect with Facebook", and in a UIWebView, I called a URL which show a html page with "facebook comment box" integrated. That works well excepte :

- In the webview, it shows the button "log in facebook to post" even if the user is connected to facebook in application (by fbsdk). Because the connection session fb in the webpage is independent with that of my application.
- In the app, event if the use connected by webview, he can not share message without another "login" by fbsdk. For the same reason.

I'd like to know is there a method to share le session fb between the uiwebview and application? 
Thanks!